# In QFT when performing path integral, why don’t we divide it by the volume of Poincaré group, as what we did for gauge group?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, gauge-theory, group-theory, path-integral

When performing path integral in gauge theory, we naively want to compute
$$
Z = \int DA \exp(iS[A])
$$
But we noticed, that because the action is the same for gauge equivalent conditions, we should actually divide it by the volume of the gauge group:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z =& \frac{1}{\text{Vol(Gauge)}}\int DA \exp(iS[A])\\
=& \int DA \exp(iS[A]) \delta(G(A)) \det(\frac{\delta G}{\delta \theta})
\\
\end{aligned}
$$
This is the well known Faddeev-Popov method and this is where ghosts come.

But why didn’t we divide the path integral by the volume of the Poincaré group before? Since the action is the same for two fields differ by a Poincaré transformation:
$$
S[\phi] = S[\tilde{\phi}], \quad \tilde{\phi}(\Lambda x + a) = \phi(x)
$$
So why didn’t we perform
$$
Z = \frac{1}{\text{Vol(Poincare)}} \int D\phi \exp(iS[\phi])~?
$$

Comment: A gauge symmetry is a redundancy in our description of the theory. The Poincare symmetry is an actual physical symmetry.

Comment: @Prahar Yeah I know that intuitively speaking it must be the reason. But I wonder how can be this turn into a more mathematical argument? Is that because the boundary condition on a 3-dimensional hypersurface (I.e. a state) is invariant?

Answer (score 0):

We should consider the generating function $Z[J]$ rather that just the partition function $Z = Z[0]$, because it computes the correlation functions which contain the physical content of the theory.

If you perform the Fadeev-Popov gauge fixing procedure without dividing first by the volume of the gauge group, you would find that (provided that $\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0$ so that gauge invariance is preserved) :
$$
\int DA \exp(iS[A,J])=\text{Vol(Gauge)} \int DA \exp(iS[A,J]) \delta(G(A)) \det(\frac{\delta G}{\delta \theta})
$$
Because the overall normalization of the path integral is unphysical (it does not change the correlation functions), we are free to divide by the $\text{Vol(Gauge)}$ factor so that we get just a regular path integral with ghosts :
$$
Z[J] = \frac{1}{\text{Vol(Gauge)}}\int DA \exp(iS[A,J])= \int DA Db Dc \exp(iS_{FP}[A,b,c,J]) 
$$

There is no way to do this kind of manipulations for Poincaré invariance because $Z[J]$ is not Poincaré invariant, but rather covariant : $Z[J] = Z[J^\Lambda]$.

Comment: Thanks! But I can’t see why $S[A, J]$ is gauge invariant in nonabelian case…..Besides, in your last sentence do you originally want to say $S[A, J]$ instead of $ Z[J]$ ?